# How to emulate Task.Wait using threads

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to emulate this code:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
t.Wait()
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task) Tasks cannot set apartment state. Apartment state can be set using Threads but I need the Wait functionality in Tasks. Is there a way to emulate the Wait() function using Threads?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the blocking until the Task is complete, or do you need to interact with async/await/TPL?

Comment: Are you just starting one task in another thread and immediately blocking until it completes?  If so, then just call it synchronously.

Comment: @mbeckish That's not an option if you're not on an STA thread and the method needs to be run on an STA thread.

Comment: You may user (Auto/Manual)ResetEvent. Pass instance into task and set event on task complete. Outside task, after start, user WaitOne or similar method

Comment: @Uzzy 1) He doesn't have a task.  He has a `Thread`.  He's asking how to wait on a thread.  2) Why would you do all of that when there's a single method that already exists that does *exactly* what he needs?

Answer (score 5):

`Thread.Join` will block the current thread until another thread completes.

Oh, and for the record, the statement `Tasks cannot set apartment state` isn't correct.  Perhaps `StartNew` will never create a task that represents work in an STA thread, but some other method *could* create a `Task` that represented work in an STA thread.  For example, this one does:

```
public static Task<T> StartSTATask<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            tcs.SetResult(func());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tcs.SetException(e);
        }
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

(You can create one for `Task` that will look almost identical, or add overloads for some of the various options that `StartNew` has.)

Comment: This looks nice. How would I convert this method to use an Action instead?

Comment: @Luke101 You Change the signature as appropriate and just set a dummy value in the TCS.  It's pretty much just copy-paste.