# Watin with system.Threading.tasks.Task throw ThreadStateException

Tags: c#, multithreading, watin

I am using Watin inside Task which throw exception

```
ThreadStateException with an error message of 'The CurrentThread needs to have its ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer'
```

My code is look like

```
 Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
              try{
                     string  Url="www.google.com";
                     IE ie = new IE(Url);
                }
               catch (Exception ex)
             {
             throw ex; //ThreadStateException 
             }    
});
```

How can i solve this problem?
I am trying to google but unable to find solution.

Comment: If you care about what kind of thread the task needs to run on, maybe you should just be creating a thread instead. You can wrap it in a method that uses `TaskCompletionSource` to expose a `Task`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16722767/1726343

Answer (score 1):

Nothing "wrong" with the code. Read this on the WatIn documentation:

http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/

From the documentation:

> Behaviour of WatiN when Thread is not an STA Thread.
>
> WatiN will throw a ThreadStateException when you create an instance of
>   the WatiN.Core.IE class, to help you remind to set the ApartmentState
>   to STA.