# Inserting Image to FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, flowdocument

I'm working on a wpf application. I want to create a FlowDocument object and print it. As the creation step takes some seconds and freeze the UI, I move my code to new thread. The problem is that I need to set an Image in the FlowDocument and need to create Image UIElement, but UI Controls cannot be created in background threads !
I've also tried so many Dispather.Invoke() scenarios, but they catch exception about object owner thread.

I wonder is there any other methods to insert image into the FlowDocument? Or is it possible to create Image UIElement in background thread?

any suggestion would be appreciated.

P.S : Some Example Code =>

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = SingletonSetting.GetInstance().Logo;
Image v = new Image() { Source = bitmapImage };
currnetrow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(v)));




Image v = ((App)Application.Current).Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<Image>(() =>
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = SingletonSetting.GetInstance().Logo;
    return new Image() { Source = bitmapImage};
}));
currnetrow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(v)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to modify the BitmapImage, then you can freeze it and use it on the UI thread.

```
// Executing on non UI Thread
BitmapImage bitmapImage = SingletonSetting.GetInstance().Logo;
bitmapImage.Freeze(); // Has to be done on same thread it was created on - maybe freeze it in the Singleton instead?

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    // Executing on UI Thread
    Image v = new Image() { Source = bitmapImage };
    currnetrow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(v)));
});
```

After chatting with you, what you really needed to do was run your task in a STA thread, since you were making UI controls on it.
How to do that? See this answer:

[Set ApartmentState on a Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it cause exception on the last line. It say "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Comment: the currnetrow.Cells... line? What thread was currnetrow made on?

Comment: yes, the background thread create it ! I suppose using currentrow in the UI thread is the problem !

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke() run the code on the UI thread. Isn't It? I bring out the last line, but again same error, this time I suppose v cannot be accessed in the background thread.

Comment: yes all the code is on non UI thread, except those two line on the dispatcher which is on UI thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122548/discussion-between-j-h-and-evil).