# Sparx EA .feap projects images saved as blank

Tags: c#, firebird, enterprise-architect

In addin for Sparx EA I use this code to get pictures and assign to entity. Then I use images from entities, to, as example, save at some folders or insert in word report etc (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140684/1678567))

```
/// <summary>
/// Access to diagram image without using clipboard
/// </summary>
/// <param name="projectInterface">Ea Sparx interface</param>
/// <param name="eaDiagramGuid">Guid of the diagramm</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Image GetDiagramImage(this Project projectInterface, Guid eaDiagramGuid, ApplicationLogger _logger)
{
    Image diagramImage;
    try
    {
        var diagramByGuid = projectInterface.GUIDtoXML(eaDiagramGuid.ToString("B"));
        string tempFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".png");
        bool imageToFileSuccess = projectInterface.PutDiagramImageToFile(diagramByGuid, tempFilename, FileExtensionByName);

        if (imageToFileSuccess)
        {
            using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilename)))
            {
                diagramImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
            }


            File.Delete(tempFilename);
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Image to file exprot fail {0}", projectInterface.GetLastError()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return diagramImage;
}
```

The problem is - it works if project I work with saved as `.eap` file.

If it's `.feap` file, which, as I believe means that it works with `Firebird` database (instead of `Access`), all saved/exproted to report images are blank, like this down below

[image]

Why does it happens and is there workaround?

**UPD**

It works if I use `projectInterface.PutDiagramImageOnClipboard` instead but I don't wont to use `clipboard` at all

**UPD 2**

After some experiments today at the morning (at my timezone, gmt+3, it's still morning) I found out that the problem was with **GUIDs** register!

After I decided to apply `.toUpper()` here

> `var diagramByGuid = projectInterface.GUIDtoXML(eaDiagramGuid.ToString("B").ToUpper());`

it started work fine!

[image]

Strange thing thou that if project is `*.EAP` type everything works even when guid is not in upper register!

**UPD3**

Well, unfortunately, I was wrong. *Some* pictures are still blank. But somehow that changes got impact on diagrams, I keep testing this stuff.

And some of the pictures are appeared twice or in wrong place.
But it's kinda interesting (if I could say so) behaviour.

**UPD 4**

I was wrong in my **UPD2** part! GUID can contain down register symbols as well as upper ones. 
So, first I removed that part.
What I done next - I started to pass GUID directly from diagram, so signature changed like that

> `public static Image GetDiagramImage(this Project projectInterface, string eaDiagramGuid, ApplicationLogger _logger)`

and `eaDiagramGuid` should be passed right from `EA.Diagram` object.

When we parse it as `Guid` by `Guid.Parse(eaDiagramGuid)` it convert everything in lowercase like here

[image]

so, thats why I got the problem.

But for some reason it was not appeared in `*.EAP` type of projects!

Also it strange that register matters in that case, really. Seems like GUID in common and GUID in sparx ea are different things!

Comment: This sounds more like a support question that should be addressed to Sparx systems.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hmm, maybe, I believe I'm not first who faced such problem but googling on that not helped

Comment: I'd also report this as bug: http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html

Comment: @ThomasKilian oh, well, good idea, I'll report it. But also I think I'll wait what mr. Bellekens would say about that

Comment: Pretty sure Geert will say the same :-) And reporting that won't hurt. In the "worst case" they tell you, what you're doing wrong ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian thank you, I reported about it, and also attached link to this question (hope it's legal to include it in report).
Still wondering why I cant find anything on it. Seems like `*.feap` is not really popular format

Comment: IIRC it has been introduced around V10. EAP is probably the most popular format (besides RDBMS usage).

Comment: @ThomasKilian today I found out that is (at least by half-part) my fault! check the question update. And, damn, in `*EAP` projects it dosent really matters which register of guid string you got

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it *as an answer*. Not as an edit to your *question*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, actually I still testing it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and seems like in some cases pictures are still empty

Comment: I seem to remember a thread with pictures and clipboard on Sparx forum. But searching that is a real PITA :-(

Comment: @ThomasKilian yeah, I know how it is)

Comment: @ThomasKilian damn, I was stupid, I got it now! See the UPD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as I founded out here, the thing is, in case of `*.FEAP` all items GUIDs are surprisingly case sensetive.

So, my mistake was to store item GUID as `Guid` type - when we use `Guid.Parse(myGuidString)` function and then we converting it back to string - all symbols are appers to be in lowercase.

Also, I got my answer from support (they were surprisingly fast, I really like that)

> Hello Danil,
>
> Running over the Stack Overflow - it sounds like it's effectively
>   answered.  The core point is that the Feap files are case sensitive. 
>   To be technical, the collation used for our Firebird databases is case
>   sensitive.
>
> So, in the Automation script you do need to adhere to the case.

So, I just change things to work directly with GUID string from project item like

`Image diagramImage = _eaProjectInterface.GetDiagramImage(diagram.DiagramGUID, _logger);`

and function now look like this

```
    public static Image GetDiagramImage(this Project projectInterface, string eaDiagramGuid, ApplicationLogger _logger)
    {
        Image diagramImage;

        try
        {
            var diagramByGuid = projectInterface.GUIDtoXML(eaDiagramGuid);
            string tempFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".png");
            bool imageToFileSuccess = projectInterface.PutDiagramImageToFile(diagramByGuid, tempFilename, FileExtensionByName);

            if (imageToFileSuccess)
            {
                using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilename)))
                {
                    diagramImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
                }

                File.Delete(tempFilename);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Image to file exprot fail {0}", projectInterface.GetLastError()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return diagramImage;
    }
```

So, this means that Sparx EA `*.FEAP` project GUIDs are **NOT** really GUIDs but just string-keys  (as I assume).

Be careful when your work with them :-)

Comment: I think Sparx should declare columns containing guids either with a case insensitive collation, or - better - to use `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` and convert between bytes and human readable guids with [`CHAR_TO_UUID`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-char_to_uuid) and [`UUID_TO_CHAR`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-uuid_to_char)