# Is it possible to await Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sta

I am in a situation where I have to spawn a new thread manually, so I am able to can call `.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`. This means (as far as I know) that I cannot use `Task`. But I would like to know when the thread was done running, something like the `await` which works with `async`. However, the best I can come up with is a loop, constantly checking `Thread.IsAlive`, like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{ 
    // my code here 
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

while(thread.IsAlive)
{
    // Wait 100 ms
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

This should work (as long as the thread don't end up stalling), but it seems kind of clumsy. Isn't there a more clever way to check when the thread is done (or dead)?

It is only to avoid blocking the GUI thread, so any minor performance hits are fine (like some hundred milliseconds).

Comment: You are looking for a really weird solution, instead, explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `Thread.Join()`?

Comment: What I am trying to do is essentially `await Task.Run()`. But I cannot do that, due to the STA constraint. I can do `Thread.Join()` but doesn’t that block the UI thread in the meanwhile?

Comment: I forgot the ApartmentState part in my example. I have added it now. My bad.

Comment: Would your actual issue be solved by this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task

Comment: `Thread.Join()` would block the UI only if Thread is the UI thread.

Comment: What you are trying to do here is extremely dangerous.  You have not told us why you wrote this code, but very high odds that you're trying to suppress an exception, telling you that your code is not thread-safe.  It just shoot the messenger, it truly is unsafe and you won't have a shot at debugging the occasional deadlock or rendering glitch.  The kind that notoriously don't happen when you debug.  You must use Task.ContinueWith(), passing the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext as the scheduler to get it right.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not trying to suppress anything, I just thought that I could not use `Task`, since I needed `Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` :-). Following up on this post, I ended up finding an even smarter way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873865/catch-exception-after-thread-is-done/58874227?noredirect=1#comment104018797_58874227

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch exception after thread is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873865/catch-exception-after-thread-is-done)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an extension method you could use to enable the awaiting of threads (inspired from this article: [await anything](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/)).

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Thread thread)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        thread.Join(); // Let's be extra sure that the thread has finished
    }).GetAwaiter();
}
```

Usage example:

```
Thread thread = new(() =>
{ 
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate some background work
});
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
await thread; // Wait asynchronously until the thread is completed
```

Comment: Really nice idea. Do you think it would be possibe to include `thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` and `thread.Start()` in there somehow? So it can be run in a similar manner to a traditional async method...

Comment: The `GetAwaiter` method just enables the `await` operator for threads. The creation of the thread with its desired properties can be done as usual. I updated my answer with a complete example.

Comment: Your other answer here is a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62272927/8173870

Comment: @HackSlash this answer assumes that you are just handed a `Thread` instance, and you don't have authority over what code is running on that thread. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task/62272927#62272927) assumes full authority.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use the BackgroundWorker class? It has an event that reports when its finished.

Comment: I tried that. It appears that the `BackgroundWorker` class runs in MTA and cannot be changed.