# C# System.Thread.ThreadStateException

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to Initialize Web Browser Component in window form but I am getting this exception message

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.'
```

I am getting above mentioned Exception Message on this line

```
this.browse = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

Flag your Main() method with [STAThread] like below:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // your code
}
```

or, if the Web Browser Component should be called from inside of ant thread you created, set proper Apartment State for this thread:

```
yourThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add STAThread attribute above your main method.

Answer (score 0):

Although too late for OP, I'd like to register here the solution that worked for me.

I got the same error msg in the same position at `InitializeComponent();`

```
this.browse = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

And same error msg after change control to:

```
this.axAcroPDF1 = new AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF();
```

I tried:

```
var thread = new Thread(async () =>
{
    using var showDoc = new ShowDoc();
    showDoc.ShowDocTask(_path, OriginalFileName, FileNameExtension);
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
thread.Start();
thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
```

And same error.

Finally, I saw [How to force a task to run on an STA thread? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531973/2752308) that has a Stephen Cleary very interesting answer, and pointed me to the [Set ApartmentState on a Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task) that solved this problem.

The [Servy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722767/2752308) and [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35351613/2752308) answers has the code for implement, respectively, a

```
public static Task<T> StartSTATask<T>(Func<T> func)
```

and a

```
public static Task StartSTATask(Action func)
```

both use `new TaskCompletionSource<object>()` to carry back to the caller the Result or Exception that results from the Action or Func that is passed to a thread, that as VillageTech has pointed, has to be setted to  `thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`. Only after all pieces in place they do a `thread.Start();` and both return a (TaskCompletionSource) `tcs.Task` i.e., the Result or Exception.

Very complex to think on my on, but after seeing, is as brilliant as is obvious.

PS:
I learned a lot in these links; after that, I returned to the MS pages and I finally I understood them a lot too:

[How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-wrap-eap-patterns-in-a-task) and [TPL and traditional .NET asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming),