# Run Form simultaneously with Program

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, invalidoperationexception

I have a class that attempts to create an better alternative to the `System.Console` class. It started as follows:

```cs
public class SuperConsole
{
    private readonly Form _Form;
    public SuperConsole()
    {
        _Form = new()
        {
            Text = DefaultTitle,
            BackColor = DefaultBackColor,
        };
        Application.Run(_Form);
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get => _Form.Invoke(() => _Form.Text);
        set => _Form.Invoke(() => _Form.Text = value);
    }
    //more stuff
}
```

Obviously, if I ran the constructor, it would freeze on `Application.Run`. The form would run, of course, but the caller of the constructor would have to wait a bit. So, I changed the constructor to run `Application.Run` on a new thread:

```cs
public SuperConsole()
{
    _Form = new()
    {
        Text = DefaultTitle,
        BackColor = DefaultBackColor,
    };
    Thread t = new(() => Application.Run(_Form));
    t.Start();
}
```

But this throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

I have no idea how to proceed. I have tried several variations to this, to no effect.

I would like both the form and the calling function to be able to run simultaneously, and be able to still use `Form.Invoke` normally. I also would seek to have the user of the class not have to worry about any of this. How might I do this?

Comment: I think you need to instantiate the entire class in a thread, not just the form.

Comment: @NickAbbot I considered that. The field is declared `readonly`, so no method can change it but the constructor. Even if I got rid of the `readonly`, I would still have to call `Application.Run` in the same function. That would prevent it from returning, so I couldn't just wait for it to be initialized with `Thread.Join`. As such, that'd quickly become real ugly.

Comment: It may be necessary, however. I was just hoping for a cleaner alternative.

Comment: Win32 windows have thread-affinity (their message are delivered through a message queue of the thread, and they are immediately destroyed if the thread that created them exits).  Therefore "prevent it from returning, so I couldn't just wait for it to be initialized with Thread.Join" is indeed true.

Comment: You cannot create, access, or modify any UI element that is not on the UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you have to create the `Form` on the dedicated `SuperConsole` thread, not on the current thread, because UI components are thread-affine. You also have to declare the `SuperConsole` thread as STA, and wait until the form is created. Something like this should work:

```
public class SuperConsole
{
    private Form _form;

    public SuperConsole()
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim mres = new();
        Thread t = new(() =>
        {
            _form = new()
            {
                Text = DefaultTitle,
                BackColor = DefaultBackColor,
            };
            mres.Set();
            Application.Run(_form);
        });
        t.Name = "SuperConsole";
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        mres.Wait();
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get => _form.Invoke(() => _Form.Text);
        set => _form.Invoke(() => _Form.Text = value);
    }
}
```

The [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) is used for signaling that the `Form` instance has been created, and assigned to the `_form` field. Otherwise the current thread could observe the `_form` to be `null`.

I haven't tested the above code. It is possible that the form might not be ready for calling `Invoke` before the message loop has started. In that case you may have to move the `mres.Set();` inside the [`HandleCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated) or `Load` or `Shown` event of the form. To learn how to subscribe to an event for one notification only, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394112/parallel-using-of-webview2-in-async-task/66400598#66400598).

Answer (score -1):

I found the following solution, similar to user [@TheodorZoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549)'s hypothesis.

```cs
public SuperConsole()
{
    _Form = new()
    {
        Text = DefaultTitle,
        BackColor = DefaultBackColor,
    };
    ManualResetEventSlim mres = new();
    _Form.HandleCreated += HandleCreated;
    Thread t = new(() => Application.Run(_Form));
    t.Start();
    mres.Wait();
    void HandleCreated(object? Sender, EventArgs E)
    {
        mres.Set();
        _Form.HandleCreated -= HandleCreated;
    }
}
```

Special thanks to user [@TheodorZoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549) for pointing out why my last attempt was suboptimal. I borrowed his idea of using the `ManualResetEventSlim` class and the `Form.HandleCreated` event.

However, the form does not require being constructed on the same thread as on which the `Application.Run` function is called.

Comment: Does it still work correctly if you set the static [`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls) property to `true`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It does. I checked.

Comment: Don't create the form on a different thread. Theo's answer is correct. This is not. If it works then you are lucky, and you will be until you are not.

Comment: @Enigmativity my guess is that Brendan wants to keep the `_Form` field as `readonly`, which is a reasonable desire and my answer fails to do.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - A private setter would do that.

Comment: ​@Enigmativity the `_Form` is a field, not a property, and it's already private.